# TypeScript - Cannot be strict with types wihen defining an instance on the fly

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following `TypeScript` code which compiles properly.

My goal here is to be strict on terms of types.

When defining `user1` instance I get this effect successfully. I mean, I'm forced to define all the members for `IUser`. For example, if I don't specify the `id` property for `user1`, then when I try to compile, the `TypeScript` linter throws the following error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
error TS2322: Type '{ username: string; password: string; email: string; age: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IUser'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type '{ username: string; password: string; email: string; age: number; }'.
```

But in the other hand, as you can see for the user corresponding to: `Steve Jobs` I didn't used the property: `id` but the linter doesn't throw any error.

I'm looking for a way to define a user on the fly like that second user (not declaring another variable like the first user) and be strict with the types at the same time. I tried with the angle brackets with no success.

```
interface IUser {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email: string;
    age: number;
}

let user1: IUser = {
    id: 1,
    username: 'Bill Gates',
    password: 'windows',
    email: 'billgates@microsoft.com',
    age: 61
};

var outputObject = function(obj: any) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

outputObject(user1);

outputObject(<IUser> {
    username: 'Steve Jobs',
    password: 'mac',
    email: 'stevejobs@apple.com',
    age: 62
});
```

Any idea on how to get this work?

Thanks!

Comment: You are asserting that the anonymous object is an `IUser`, that's why TypeScript is happy with it. If `outputUser` expects an `IUser`, change its signature: `outputUser = function(obj: IUser)`

Comment: sorry, I did a mistake, the name of the function should be: `outputObject` which should accept whatever kiind of object. When providing the second user I would like to be strict with types. I know if I declare the argument of that function as `IUser` it will work but I don't want to do that because that argument could be of whatever type.

Comment: To effect the error you are looking for, you need an assignment to a variable or parameter with the type `IUser`. Asserting that it is an `IUser` isn't going to do it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13788#issuecomment-276430700

Comment: thanks, that helped

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear from your question, but it appears you are looking form `Partial<T>`. `Partial<T>` transforms the type `T` to have all properties optional. You can use `Partial<IUser>` as the parameter to `outputObject`, or we can keep `outputObject` and add a generic parameter to it that we can then specify explicitly as `Partial<IUser>` to get checking on the parameter passed in :

```
var outputObject = function<T>(obj: T) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

outputObject<Partial<IUser>>({
    username: 'Steve Jobs',
    password: 'mac',
    email: 'stevejobs@apple.com',
    age: 62
});

outputObject<Partial<IUser>>({
    age: '62' // Error incompatible types
});
```